# WP7 EndPointNotFound exception for transporting an entity over WCF?

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-7, entity

So I'm experiencing a strange error. I have a WP7 application that has a service reference to a WCF service I wrote. The WCF has an entity model for the database.

Basically what I want to happen, is when a user logs in on the phone, the matching SystemUser entry is returned from the WCF service. SystemUser is a table in the db.

On the WCF service side I have the following:

```
public SystemUser UserLogin(string emailAddress, string userPassword)
    {
        Regex emailRegex = new Regex(@"^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$");
        if (emailRegex.IsMatch(emailAddress) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(userPassword))
        {
            using (var context = new DBEntities())
            {
                var users = context.SystemUsers.Where(su => su.EmailAddress.ToLower().Trim() == emailAddress.ToLower().Trim());

                // there should only be one user in here!
                if (users.Count() <= 0)
                {
                    return null;
                }
                else
                {
                    return users.FirstOrDefault();
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Nothing too hardcore. And when the phone calls that method, it throws an EndPointNotFoundException when trying to return the SystemUser object. "There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:49676/Service1.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details." The inner exception is: "{"The remote server returned an error: NotFound."}"

The generated code that has this problem is here:

```
   public ServiceProxy.UserLoginResponse EndUserLogin(System.IAsyncResult result) {
        object[] _args = new object[0];
        PhoneApp.ServiceProxy.UserLoginResponse _result = ((PhoneApp.ServiceProxy.UserLoginResponse)(base.EndInvoke("UserLogin", _args, result)));
        return _result;
    }
```

It basically looks like it cannot transport the entity? Any ideas? I thought I didn't need to use POCO objects?

Comment: If I change the returned object to say an integer it works just fine. However it is not happy sending the entity created object through. Do I need to setup something specific with the entity model?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok what I did to fix this issue is to right click on blank space in the edmx designer and choose "Add Code Generated Item". From there I picked ADO.NET Self-Tracking Entity Generator. Works beautifully now!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have [OperationContract] before Method Name?

http://localhost:49676/Service1.svc is working in browser?

Comment: Yeah. OperationContract attribute is specified in the interface. And the service is running and working in the browser.